# Using arrays in shell script

Tags: shell-script, array

I'm trying to store the pathway to a website in an array, but am having trouble.

It is working in the for loop - when I echo the contents of the array, it prints correctly.

In the If/Else, though, I am trying to store a specific part of the array in another variable, and that is not working.  When I echo the specific part of the array, it prints nothing.

Here is the code:

```
#! /bin/sh

SITES=()
i=0

for d in /var/www/sites/*/;
do (
    PATHWAY=$d
    SITES+=($PATHWAY)
    echo "$i: $PATHWAY"
);  let "i++"
done

read -p 'Enter the number of the website you want to restore. Enter "exit" to quit. ' url

if [ "$url" = "exit" ]
then
    exit 0

else
    RESTORE_URL=${SITES[url]}
fi
```

Comment: why not use `select path in /var/www/sites/*; do [...]; done`?

Comment: You are missing a `$` on `url`.  Should be: `RESTORE_URL=${SITES[$url]}`.  Also I guess it's not functionally any different but you should use `declare -a SITES` instead of `SITES=()`

Comment: Does /bin/sh support arrays?

Comment: @Jesse_b I had tried it with both of those, previously, and it still did not work.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I guess it depends on what OS is being used.  `/bin/sh` is normally a symlink to bash though.  @Kimberlie, try again.  Your issue is that `url` doesn't have a `$`.

Comment: @Jesse_b I tried it again, and it still is not working.  Now it looks like: RESTORE_URL=${SITES[$url]}

Comment: The echo looks like echo "Test: $RESTORE_URL" is that correct?

Comment: @Jesse_b: on _some_ distros /bin/sh is or may be bash but on some it isn't. In shells that have indexed arrays at all (bash, ksh, zsh AFAIR) the `[subscript]` is treated as an arithmetic expression and `${ary[var]}` works just as well as `${ary[$var]}` Kimberlie: the actual problem is adding to SITES inside a subshell (due to the parentheses) so those changes are lost when returning to the main shell; remove the parentheses (and extra semicolon).

Comment: @KimberlieDavis, what echo?  the one in your for loop?  If you are trying to use an associative array you may need to upgrade your bash.  Also just for clarity, what OS are you using?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, *most* distros point to bash.  Also I see what you are saying now but your statement about SITES being in a subshell confused me at first.  The whole for loop is in a sub shell and should be removed, the parentheses around `$PATHWAY` need to remain.

Comment: @Jesse_b: the first three commands in the body of the for loop are in 'command' parens and hence a subshell, but not the `let i++` and not the `for` itself. Yes the parens in the SITES+= (which mean array not subshell) do need to be kept, sorry I wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good place to use a `select` statement:

```
select path in /var/www/sites/* EXIT; do
    if [[ "EXIT" = "$path" ]]; then
        exit 0
    else
        : do stuff here referencing $path
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure select is best for what I need...what the script is doing is listing the sites from the server, and then connecting to another server to pull a backup file.  So, the path is just for the sake of displaying what sites are on the server (as they should also be on the backup server), and then I take the filename from there to pull from the backup server.  What I was hoping to use an array for is to connect each filename to a number, that the user can enter when going to pull from the backup server.

Comment: @KimberlieDavis: that's almost exactly what `select` does; it displays a numbered list of strings and lets the user enter a number to select one of the strings. Without an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop (with my indentation):

```
for d in /var/www/sites/*/; do
    (   PATHWAY=$d
        SITES+=($PATHWAY)
        echo "$i: $PATHWAY"  )

    let "i++"
done
```

Notice how most of the loop body is in a subshell?  This means that the changes to those variables won't be seen outside of that subshell, and that they are reset for each iteration in the loop.

Ether change the `(...)` to `{...;}` or remove them completely.

A better alternative for the script as a whole would be to use `select` as [DopeGhoti explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399450/116858).